# TF difference between including or not including optimizer in session run

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following code (only 2 iterations and I am not retrieving new batchs in the below code for simplicity):

```
for i in range(2):
    if (i % reset_point) != 0 or i == 0:
        char_id_batch, word_id_batch, pos_id_batch = Reader.retrieve_batch_sent(start, batch_size_counter, remote_or_not)
        feed_dict = {char_id: char_id_batch, word_id: word_id_batch, y: pos_id_batch}
        _, predicted_output_result, y_reshape_result, correct_prediction_result, acc_result = sess.run([train_op, 
                                    predicted_output, 
                                    y_reshape, 
                                    correct_prediction, 
                                    accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        y_pred = []
        y_actu = []
        for j in range(len(predicted_output_result)):
            y_pred.append(predicted_output_result[j].tolist().index(max(predicted_output_result[j])))
            y_actu.append(y_reshape_result[j].tolist().index(max(y_reshape_result[j])))
        y_actu = pd.Series(y_actu, name='Actual')
        y_pred = pd.Series(y_pred, name='Predicted')
        df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_actu, y_pred)
        print(df_confusion)
        print('accuracy at iteration %d is: %0.3f' % (i, acc_result))


        predicted_output_result1, acc_result1 = sess.run([predicted_output, accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        y_pred = []
        y_actu = []
        for j in range(len(predicted_output_result1)):
            y_pred.append(predicted_output_result1[j].tolist().index(max(predicted_output_result1[j])))
            y_actu.append(y_reshape_result[j].tolist().index(max(y_reshape_result[j])))
        y_actu = pd.Series(y_actu, name='Actual')
        y_pred = pd.Series(y_pred, name='Predicted')
        df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_actu, y_pred)
        print(df_confusion)
        print('accuracy at iteration %d is: %0.3f' % (i, acc_result1))


        predicted_output_result2, acc_result2= sess.run([predicted_output, accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        y_pred = []
        y_actu = []
        for j in range(len(predicted_output_result2)):
            y_pred.append(predicted_output_result2[j].tolist().index(max(predicted_output_result2[j])))
            y_actu.append(y_reshape_result[j].tolist().index(max(y_reshape_result[j])))
        y_actu = pd.Series(y_actu, name='Actual')
        y_pred = pd.Series(y_pred, name='Predicted')
        df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_actu, y_pred)
        print(df_confusion)
        print('accuracy at iteration %d is: %0.3f' % (i, acc_result2))
```

When I run, I get the following results (not showing all):

```
Predicted   0     8   10
Actual                  
0           27  4132   0
1           38    87   7
2           79   173   2
accuracy at iteration 0 is: 0.004

Predicted    12
Actual         
0          4159
1           132
2           254
accuracy at iteration 0 is: 0.081

Predicted    12
Actual         
0          4159
1           132
2           254
accuracy at iteration 0 is: 0.081

Predicted    12
Actual         
0          4159
1           132
2           254
accuracy at iteration 1 is: 0.081

Predicted    14
Actual         
0          4159
1           132
2           254
accuracy at iteration 1 is: 0.072

Predicted    14
Actual         
0          4159
1           132
2           254
accuracy at iteration 1 is: 0.072
```

As you can see, the second and thrid results of `iteration 0`, are repeated. Also in the first session run of `iteration 1`. But the second result of `iteration 1` changes, where as the third result of `iteration 1` is the same as the second result of `iteration 1`.

Whereas, if I include `train_op` in all three session runs, I am getting different results.

1. Can someone explain what is going on? Why the difference between including and not including `train_op`?
2. Which one is correct, i.e., should I include `train_op` or not? Is there a huge influence, positive or negative in accuracy, if I include or not include `train_op`?

I have the following code (only 2 iterations and I am not retrieving new batchs in the below code for simplicity):

```
for i in range(2):
    if (i % reset_point) != 0 or i == 0:
        char_id_batch, word_id_batch, pos_id_batch = Reader.retrieve_batch_sent(start, batch_size_counter, remote_or_not)
        feed_dict = {char_id: char_id_batch, word_id: word_id_batch, y: pos_id_batch}
        _, predicted_output_result, y_reshape_result, correct_prediction_result, acc_result = sess.run([train_op, 
                                    predicted_output, 
                                    y_reshape, 
                                    correct_prediction, 
                                    accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        y_pred = []
        y_actu = []
        for j in range(len(predicted_output_result)):
            y_pred.append(predicted_output_result[j].tolist().index(max(predicted_output_result[j])))
            y_actu.append(y_reshape_result[j].tolist().index(max(y_reshape_result[j])))
        y_actu = pd.Series(y_actu, name='Actual')
        y_pred = pd.Series(y_pred, name='Predicted')
        df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_actu, y_pred)
        print(df_confusion)
        print('accuracy at iteration %d is: %0.3f' % (i, acc_result))


        predicted_output_result1, acc_result1 = sess.run([predicted_output, accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        y_pred = []
        y_actu = []
        for j in range(len(predicted_output_result1)):
            y_pred.append(predicted_output_result1[j].tolist().index(max(predicted_output_result1[j])))
            y_actu.append(y_reshape_result[j].tolist().index(max(y_reshape_result[j])))
        y_actu = pd.Series(y_actu, name='Actual')
        y_pred = pd.Series(y_pred, name='Predicted')
        df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_actu, y_pred)
        print(df_confusion)
        print('accuracy at iteration %d is: %0.3f' % (i, acc_result1))


        predicted_output_result2, acc_result2= sess.run([predicted_output, accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        y_pred = []
        y_actu = []
        for j in range(len(predicted_output_result2)):
            y_pred.append(predicted_output_result2[j].tolist().index(max(predicted_output_result2[j])))
            y_actu.append(y_reshape_result[j].tolist().index(max(y_reshape_result[j])))
        y_actu = pd.Series(y_actu, name='Actual')
        y_pred = pd.Series(y_pred, name='Predicted')
        df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_actu, y_pred)
        print(df_confusion)
        print('accuracy at iteration %d is: %0.3f' % (i, acc_result2))
```

When I run, I get the following results (not showing all):

```
Predicted   0     8   10
Actual                  
0           27  4132   0
1           38    87   7
2           79   173   2
accuracy at iteration 0 is: 0.004

Predicted    12
Actual         
0          4159
1           132
2           254
accuracy at iteration 0 is: 0.081

Predicted    12
Actual         
0          4159
1           132
2           254
accuracy at iteration 0 is: 0.081

Predicted    12
Actual         
0          4159
1           132
2           254
accuracy at iteration 1 is: 0.081

Predicted    14
Actual         
0          4159
1           132
2           254
accuracy at iteration 1 is: 0.072

Predicted    14
Actual         
0          4159
1           132
2           254
accuracy at iteration 1 is: 0.072
```

As you can see, the second and thrid results of `iteration 0`, are repeated. Also in the first session run of `iteration 1`. But the second result of `iteration 1` changes, where as the third result of `iteration 1` is the same as the second result of `iteration 1`.

Whereas, if I include `train_op` in all three session runs, I am getting different results.

1. Can someone explain what is going on? Why the difference between including and not including `train_op`?
2. Which one is correct, i.e., should I include `train_op` or not? Is there a huge influence, positive or negative in accuracy, if I include or not include `train_op`?

Adding the `train_op`, `accuracy`, `predicted_output`:

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predicted_output, 1), tf.argmax(y_reshape, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)
predicted_output = tf.matmul(output_sent, h_layer_weights) + h_layer_bias
```

Answer (score 0):

First, **note**: you haven't shown the definition of `train_op`, `predicted_output`, or `accuracy`, so I am taking an educated (though fairly confident) guess at what these ops actually are in my answer below.  But if you have defined them unusually, please refine the code example (and simplify away much of it) to clarify.

That said, here's what's going on:  without `train_op`, you are just evaluating `predicted_output` and `accuracy`.  These just take the data in `feed_dict` and give you the output of the NN and the accuracy (how well it classified/predicted the target of the NN model).  **Notice** that neither of those steps actually takes a gradient step or changes the model parameters to try to explain the data better.  So you shouldn't expect your model to change, and you should thus expect accuracy to also be unchanged.

As the name implies, `train_op` is the operation that is actually taking gradient steps and training your model.  So, when you run it again in the second iteration, it will change the model, your accuracy will change (improvement would be ideal, but this is stochastic optimization, so accuracy losses are expected, as long as performance generally improves over iterations), and you will get new values, as you see in your code.

Comment: I have added the ops. But why is the second print of `iteration 0` different from first print of `iteration = 0`? After all the second and third `sess.run` do not have `train_op`, shouldn't they just fetch the values without training the NN? Also if you look at `iteration 1` first print which has `train_op` in `sess.run`, shouldn't it give a different results than previous iteration?